# Power Automate - Update specific List Item in a separate List

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, power-automate, update, date

I have a strange request that I'm trying to work out, but keep getting stuck on one aspect.  So I have a SP Online list with 20 entries - One row per staff member.  Each row contains a People column (populated with staff members' names), and 10 different Date columns.  Each Date column is titled for 10 different trainings they need to complete.  Those 10 Trainings each have their own individual List in SP Online.  Those smaller lists only contain a People column and Date column as well.  So the requested function here is this:

- I complete an HR Training.  So in the HR Training list I create a new item populated with my name and today's date.
- Power Automate flow triggers at that point, and updates the HR Training Date Column in the Staff member list with the Date entered in the HR Training list.

So how can I tell the flow to update only that User's line item when an item is created in a different list?

Hope I'm explaining this well enough -

HR Training List - I create new item with my name and today's date.
Flow updates my existing list item (HR Training Date column) in Staff list with that date entered in the HR Training List.

I'm just not sure how to tell the flow to locate one specific list item based and update one specific date column.

Comment: Are you adding your name in "HR Training List" in person or group column?

Comment: If I create a new item in the HR Training List, it populates my name (people column), and HR Training Date column in that list.  I also have an existing list item in the Staff List with my name, and a bunch of other Training Date COlumns - HR Training Date included.  So I need to the flow to update the HR Training Date column in the Staff list with the Date I entered in the HR Training List.

Comment: The main problem is telling Power Automate to only update the Staff List item with my name specifically, when I submit an item in that other list

Comment: HR Training List columns:  Team Member (People column), Training Complete Date (Date column).  Staff List columns: Staff Account Name (People Column), HR Training Date (Date Column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-can-I-update-only-1-property-in-a-SharePoint-List/td-p/82047
And: https://www.process.st/how-to/update-sharepoint-list-using-power-automate/

Trigger: Set up the trigger to specify to run when a new item is created in the HR Training list.

Get Item: Add the "Get item" action to retrieve the specific item you want to update from the Staff member list. You can use an OData (https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-to-update-a-specific-SharePoint-list-item-based-on-a/td-p/728101) query to limit the "Get Items" to only return the rows with the specific staff member’s name.

Update Item: Use the "Update item" action to modify the HR Training Date column of the retrieved item. You can specify value for the fields that you want to update.

Remember, when using the "Update item" action, you are asked to enter a value for the required field, for the other fields, you can just specify value for the fields that you want to update.